# ie8 not rendering chosen properly, and working fine when i scroll down and up

Tags: javascript, css

In my project i am using dropdown(select), in this i am using chosen js to replace the select to chzn dropdown. Its working fine in all browsers like firefox, chrome, safari, ie10 and ie9. But in ie8 its not working properly. in ie8 the dropdown is backward the main div, but when i scroll down and scroll up the dropdown is looking fine.

i tried to give the main div `z-index:0`, and inner div of dropdown is given css `z-index:9999 !important; position absolute;` but its not working.

```
#breadcrumb {z-index:0;} 
.chzn-container .chzn-drop {z-index:9999 !important; position:absolute;}
```

So please help me in this.

Comment: Please share fiddle for css.

Comment: Generally you can fix this type of bug by placing `overflow: hidden;` on the parent container... but without seeing more of your code (or a fiddle as Kishori states) it's impossible to say anything further.